# input type="radio" - only choose second option?

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I have an issue with my radio input.
It lets me change to the second option if im clicking on the label but it doesnt work for the first option. I can only choose the first option if im clicking on the selection-circle but i dont want to display it. It should work with a click on the text.
Any ideas?

```css
.switch-field {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
}

.switch-field input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.switch-field label {
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px 10%;
  margin-right: -1px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked+label {
  background-color: #cc7676;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-field">
  <input type="radio" id="strang1u3" name="switch-one" onchange="speichern(); clicksound()" />
  <label for="strang1u2">Strang 1 & 3</label>
  <input type="radio" id="strang2u4" name="switch-one" onchange="speichern(); clicksound()" />
  <label for="strang2u4">Strang 2 & 4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like a typo on your first radio id: `strang1u3` instead of `strang1u2` as is targeted by the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first label's for (strang1u2) and input's id (strang1u3) don't match. This may be causing this as the label isn't associated with the input.